# Big table with a lot of cells as variables

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout

I'm implementing a simple reservation system for an Android devices. I need to have one activity containing table with 7 days of week and hours from 7am to 8pm and I would like to be able to add some text to each of cells. My draft looks like this:
[image]

My problem is that I used Table Layout to do this and it caused the situation, where my layout code looks like that:

```
<!--7:00-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:width="40sp"
            android:text="\n7:00"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_1_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_2_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_3_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_4_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_5_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_6_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_7_1"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </TableRow>
```

As you see, to use any of those TextViews I would have to implement textview_1_1, textview_1_2 and so on. 
I am sure that there must be more elegant way to do this. Could some of you help me out?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

the best practice for this kind of problems is to use a listview with custom items(in this case edittext items)
for implementing that see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)  or just look up 'listview custom items'

then through your listview object you can access each item (getItem()) and containing information (in your case value of edittext > gettext())